# Store multiple items in a single table column in SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, grid

Currently I have

```
public void bindgrid()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select p.[name], cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select p.[name], cd.CustomerName, cd.CustomerEmailID,cd.CustomerPhoneNo,cd.CustomerAddress,cd.TotalPrice,cd.OrderDateTime, cd.PaymentMethod FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID", conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "data");

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

and the result:

[image]

What I want to happen is that since it is in the same ID (10), would it be possible if I can have multiple values inside my Name column? like lpg, oxygen, etc?

Update: so far I got

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfxBz.jpg)

I just want to store multiple values in my name column to avoid redundancy. please help

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, and something like group_concat or similar.

Comment: That structure is not a good design.  It's better to have 2 records than to store multiple items in the same column.  Or are you asking for a query that does that?

Comment: can you show me a sample sir? please sir @jarlh

Comment: @devlincarnate but as you can see sir, everything is the same like the total price.

Comment: As @devlincarnate says, it's a lousy idea to store data like that. However, displaying is another thing.

Comment: i just want it to be as one to avoid redudancy sir. please help me @jarlh

Comment: Storing data as comma separated items is really bad practice. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Avoiding redundancy isn't the goal of storing data in a relational database and there are other ways to reduce redundancy.  You still haven't clarified whether your intention is to just display the data as comma delimited values for the Name column, or to actually store the data that way.  If it's the latter, I'm bowing out because I refuse to lead someone down a bad road.

Comment: @devlincarnate so what i have now is the ideal way of storing data sir?

Comment: @devlincarnate because as you can see, the price is for 2 products combined. so it becomes redundant sir

Answer (score 1):

Separate your transactions from the items into two separate tables.  Use the transaction ID as a foreign key in the items-purchased table.  That is:

- Remove the column `name` from your existing table
- Create a new table with `name` and `Id`
- Insert just one row into your existing table with a unique `Id`
- Insert multiple rows into the new table with the same `Id` and the various names

So your second table would contain rows:

```
 Id        name
 ...
 10        Carbon Dioxide
 10        Industrial Oxygen
 11        (a different purchase)
 11        (a different purchase)
 ...
```

Comment: can you guide me through please sir

Comment: Stack Overflow is here for you to ask questions and get answers.  It is not here for experts to give you a free course in database design.  There are many excellent books and courses available to help you learn good database design.  The "For Dummies" series of books are excellent, as well as books published by O'Reilly.